# Cannot properly encode a sample text using huffman

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

The problem occurs in the `find` function where the erlang shell tells me that an exception error has occurred, it says:

`Exception error: no function clause matching seminar1:find("t", []) (seminar1.erl, line 117) in function seminar1:encode/3 ( seminar1.erl, line 113)`.

I believe what is happening is that the pattern-matching done in the first `find` function is always failing, though I do not understand why since attempts to do comparisons manually have been successful.

```
-module(seminar1).
-compile(export_all).

sample() -> "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
this is a sample text that we will use when we build
up a table we will only handle lower case letters and
no punctuation symbols the frequency will of course not
represent english but it is probably not that far off".

text() -> "this is something that we should encode".

test() ->
Sample = sample(),
Tree = tree(Sample),
Encode = encode_table(Tree),
Decode = decode_table(Tree),
Text = text(),
Seq = encode(Text, Encode),
Text = decode(Seq, Decode).


tree(Sample) -> Freq = freq(Sample),

            F = fun({node,N1,V1,_,_}, {node,N2,V2,_,_}) -> 
                    if
                        V1 > V2 -> false;
                        V1 == V2 -> if
                                    N1 > N2 -> false;
                                    true -> true
                                    end;
                        true -> true
                    end 
                end,
            %lists:sort(F,Freq).
            huffman(lists:sort(F,Freq)).


% Calculate the frequency of each letter in the Sample and return a 
datastructure of nodes containing the letter involved,
% frequency of it in the sample.
% datastructure {node, Key, Value, Left, Right}
freq(Sample) -> freq(Sample, []).

freq([], Freq) -> Freq;
freq([Char|Rest], Freq) ->  freq(Rest, check(Char, Freq)).

% Check function complements the Freq function, it takes the current input 
and pattern matches it with the frequency datastructue being built.
% If it scores a hit that particular node has its frequency incremented and 
then the whole datastructure is returned.
check(Key, []) -> [{node, [Key], 1, nil, nil}];
check(Key, [{node, [Key], Value, nil, nil}| Tail]) -> [{node, [Key], Value + 
1, nil, nil}| Tail];
check(Key, [H|T]) -> [H |check(Key, T)].

% Creates the Huffman tree that is later used to encode a sample.
% The input is the SORTED datastructure derived from the freq-function.
% The leaves of the huffman tree are where actual values reside, branches 
are just nodes containing information.
huffman( [ Tree | [] ] ) -> Tree;

huffman([{node, LeftKey, LeftValue, _L1, _R1}, 
     {node, RightKey, RightValue, _L2, _R2} |Tail]) ->

    % Creating a branch node
    BranchNode = {node, LeftKey ++ RightKey, LeftValue + RightValue, {node, 
LeftKey, LeftValue, _L1, _R1}, {node, RightKey, RightValue, _L2, _R2}},

    huffman(insert(BranchNode, Tail)).

% A complementary function to the huffman function, inserts the newly made 
branchnode into the already sorted tail.
% This is to prevent the sorted tail from becoming unsorted when turning the 
tail list into a tree.
% It is inserted as such that the branchnode is the first selection of its 
current value, 
% meaning that if you have 4 nodes of value 5 ( one being a branchnode) then 
the branch node will be the first option.
% This will make the Tree structure left leaning.
%
%             N
%         N       N
%      N    N   
%     N N   N N
insert(Node, []) -> [Node|[]];

insert(Node, [H|T]) ->
    {_, _, Nvalue, _, _} = Node,
    {_, _, Hdvalue, _, _} = H,
    if
        Nvalue =< Hdvalue -> [ Node | [H|T]];
        true -> [H | insert(Node, T)]
    end.



% Takes the tree created by the huffman-function as input and traverses said 
tree.
% Returns a list containing the letters found and their position in the 
tree, Left = 0, Right = 1.
% {"e"/[101], [0,0,0]} -- {[Key], [pathway]}
% Traversal method used: Left based traversal.
encode_table(RootNode) -> encode_table(RootNode, [], []).

% When traversing the Tree I need to know the branchnode I am in, the result 
list as I am adding letters to it and a PathwayList which is the current 
binary path to the branchnode I am in.
encode_table({_, Key, _, nil, nil}, AccList, PathwayList) ->
    [AccList | [{Key, reverse(PathwayList)}]];
encode_table({_, _, _, Left, Right}, AccList, PathwayList) ->
    encode_table(
        Right, 
        encode_table(Left, AccList, [0| PathwayList]), 
        [1|PathwayList]).

% Complementary function for the encode_table/3 function, when traversing 
the tree the the pathway gets reversed so it needs to be corrected.
reverse(L) -> reverse(L, []).
reverse([], Rev) -> Rev;
reverse([H|T], Rev) -> reverse(T, [H|Rev]).


% Takes a sample text and encodes it in accordance to the encoding table 
supplied
encode(Text, Table) -> encode(Text, Table, []).

encode([], _, EncodedText) -> EncodedText;
encode([Letter|Rest], Table, EncodedText) ->
    encode(Rest, Table, [find([Letter], Table) | EncodedText]).

% Complementary function to encode/3, searches the Table for the related 
Letters binary path.
%find(Letter, []) -> Letter;
find(Letter, [{Letter, BinaryPath} | _Rest]) -> 
    BinaryPath;
find(Letter, [ _ | Rest]) -> 
    find(Letter, Rest).

decode_table(tree) -> ok.
decode(sequence, table) -> ok.

test(Letter, [{Letter, Asd} | []]) ->
    true;
test(_, _) -> false.
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to analyse, but at least the error will disappear if you un-comment the line `%find(Letter, []) -> Letter;`

Comment: Well yes, that is true! However it does not solve the issue I am having, which is that the pattern-match for "find(Letter, [{Letter, BinaryPath} | _Rest]) -> 
    BinaryPath;" keeps failing resulting in the program just traversing the table until the very end.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to follow your code , but I am stuck on the function `decode_table(tree) -> ok.`. With this spelling, it fails (`tree` is an atom and won't match anything but `tree` itself). Change to `_Tree` to ignore the issue when I understood that the decode functions are not written yet or not provided.

For the encoding, the trouble is that the function encode_table returns a nested list, not suitable with the find function. If you replace the code by `encode_table(RootNode) -> lists:flatten(encode_table(RootNode, [], [])).` then it works (at least it seems to work since I don't know which result you are expecting)

```
-module(seminar1).
-compile(export_all).

sample() -> "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
this is a sample text that we will use when we build
up a table we will only handle lower case letters and
no punctuation symbols the frequency will of course not
represent english but it is probably not that far off".

text() -> "this is something that we should encode".

test() ->
Sample = sample(),
Tree = tree(Sample),
Encode = encode_table(Tree),
%Decode = decode_table(Tree),
Text = text(),
Seq = encode(Text, Encode),
%Text = decode(Seq, Decode).
Seq.

tree(Sample) -> Freq = freq(Sample),

            F = fun({node,N1,V1,_,_}, {node,N2,V2,_,_}) ->
                    if
                        V1 > V2 -> false;
                        V1 == V2 -> if
                                    N1 > N2 -> false;
                                    true -> true
                                    end;
                        true -> true
                    end
                end,
            %lists:sort(F,Freq).
            huffman(lists:sort(F,Freq)).


% Calculate the frequency of each letter in the Sample and return a
% datastructure of nodes containing the letter involved,
% frequency of it in the sample.
% datastructure {node, Key, Value, Left, Right}
freq(Sample) -> freq(Sample, []).

freq([], Freq) -> Freq;
freq([Char|Rest], Freq) ->  freq(Rest, check(Char, Freq)).

% Check function complements the Freq function, it takes the current input
% and pattern matches it with the frequency datastructue being built.
% If it scores a hit that particular node has its frequency incremented and
% then the whole datastructure is returned.
check(Key, []) ->
    [{node, [Key], 1, nil, nil}];
check(Key, [{node, [Key], Value, nil, nil}| Tail]) ->
    [{node, [Key], Value + 1, nil, nil}| Tail];
check(Key, [H|T]) ->
    [H |check(Key, T)].

% Creates the Huffman tree that is later used to encode a sample.
% The input is the SORTED datastructure derived from the freq-function.
% The leaves of the huffman tree are where actual values reside, branches
% are just nodes containing information.
huffman( [ Tree | [] ] ) -> Tree;

huffman([{node, LeftKey, LeftValue, _L1, _R1},
         {node, RightKey, RightValue, _L2, _R2} |Tail]) ->

    % Creating a branch node
    BranchNode = {node, LeftKey ++ RightKey, LeftValue + RightValue, {node, LeftKey, LeftValue, _L1, _R1}, {node, RightKey, RightValue, _L2, _R2}},

    huffman(insert(BranchNode, Tail)).

% A complementary function to the huffman function, inserts the newly made
% branchnode into the already sorted tail.
% This is to prevent the sorted tail from becoming unsorted when turning the
% tail list into a tree.
% It is inserted as such that the branchnode is the first selection of its
% current value,
% meaning that if you have 4 nodes of value 5 ( one being a branchnode) then
% the branch node will be the first option.
% This will make the Tree structure left leaning.
%
%             N
%         N       N
%      N    N
%     N N   N N
insert(Node, []) -> [Node|[]];

insert(Node, [H|T]) ->
    {_, _, Nvalue, _, _} = Node,
    {_, _, Hdvalue, _, _} = H,
    if
        Nvalue =< Hdvalue -> [ Node | [H|T]];
        true -> [H | insert(Node, T)]
    end.



% Takes the tree created by the huffman-function as input and traverses said tree.
% Returns a list containing the letters found and their position in the
% tree, Left = 0, Right = 1.
% {"e"/[101], [0,0,0]} -- {[Key], [pathway]}
% Traversal method used: Left based traversal.
encode_table(RootNode) -> lists:flatten(encode_table(RootNode, [], [])).

% When traversing the Tree I need to know the branchnode I am in, the result
% list as I am adding letters to it and a PathwayList which is the current
% binary path to the branchnode I am in.
encode_table({_, Key, _, nil, nil}, AccList, PathwayList) ->
    [AccList | [{Key, reverse(PathwayList)}]];
encode_table({_, _, _, Left, Right}, AccList, PathwayList) ->
    encode_table(
        Right,
        encode_table(Left, AccList, [0| PathwayList]),
        [1|PathwayList]).

% Complementary function for the encode_table/3 function, when traversing
% the tree the the pathway gets reversed so it needs to be corrected.
reverse(L) -> reverse(L, []).
reverse([], Rev) -> Rev;
reverse([H|T], Rev) -> reverse(T, [H|Rev]).


% Takes a sample text and encodes it in accordance to the encoding table supplied
encode(Text, Table) -> encode(Text, Table, []).

encode([], _, EncodedText) -> EncodedText;
encode([Letter|Rest], Table, EncodedText) ->
    encode(Rest, Table, [find([Letter], Table) | EncodedText]).

% Complementary function to encode/3, searches the Table for the related
% Letters binary path.
find(Letter, []) -> Letter;
find(Letter, [{Letter, BinaryPath} | _Rest]) ->
    BinaryPath;
find(Letter, [ _ | Rest]) ->
    find(Letter, Rest).

decode_table(_Tree) -> ok.
decode(sequence, table) -> ok.

test(Letter, [{Letter, _Asd} | []]) ->
    true;
test(_, _) -> false.
```

gives the result:

```
64> c(seminar1).             
{ok,seminar1}
65> rp(seminar1:test()).
[[0,0,0],
 [1,0,0,0,1,0],
 [0,1,1,1],
 [1,0,1,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,0,0,0,1,0],
 [1,0,0,1],
 [1,1,0,1,0],
 [0,1,1,1],
 [1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [0,0,0],
 [1,0,1,0,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,1,1],
 [1,0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0],
 [1,1,1],
 [1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,1,1],
 [1,0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [1,0,0,0,1,1,1],
 [0,1,1,1],
 [0,1,0,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [0,1,0,1],
 [1,1,0,1,1],
 [1,1,1],
 [0,1,0,1],
 [1,1,0,1,1],
 [1,0,1,0,0],
 [1,1,0,0]]
ok
66>
```

**Edit**

You will get the same result if you replace

```
encode_table({_, Key, _, nil, nil}, AccList, PathwayList) ->
    [AccList | [{Key, reverse(PathwayList)}]];
```

which is responsible for the nested result by this version which directly produces a flat list.

```
encode_table({_, Key, _, nil, nil}, AccList, PathwayList) ->
    [{Key, reverse(PathwayList)} | AccList];
```

It is the general way to build a list: `[Head|Tail]` where `Head` is any erlang term and `Tail` is a list. Your code produces a result like `[[[],{Key1,Path1}],{Key2,Path2}]` while my version gives `[{Key2,Path2},{Key1,Path1}]`

> **Some remarks :** 
>  *In erlang, the usage of `if` is not frequent, in my opinion mainly because of the last `true -> DoSomething()` clause which is in most cases very inexpressive.*
>  *Another point, searching in a list is not very fast, it is not an issue for isolate search, but in your case the encode and decode functions are doing it for each character, in my opinion, a map is more appropriate to store the Encode and Decode tables than a key/value list.*

Comment: Thank you, Pascal! I suspected that I might be accidentally creating a nested list in encode_table, though I was not sure because the Erlang Shell does not printout the entire result if it is long. I will correct that. I will also keep in mind about adding information about the desired results to my function comments in the future, as you pointed out you did not know what the result I was after.